# Serialize an object using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, c#-4.0, datacontractjsonserializer

I have created a generic extension method to serialize JSON using the DataContractJsonSerializer.
looks like this:

```
public static string ToJSON<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
       return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

I need to create a class, when serialize to json it should be like this :

```
{
     "expiration": "2011-04-20T11:54:21.032Z",
     "conditions": [
        ["eq", "acl", "private"],
        ["eq", "bucket": "myas3bucket"],
        ["eq", "$key", "myfilename.jpg"],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 20971520],
        ["eq", "$redirect", "myredirecturl"],
     ]
}
```

What are the attributes of this class?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you mean `attributes` or `properties`? And also what is the confusion, what did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
DateTime expiration { get; set; }
string[][] conditions { get; set; }
```

You could also make `conditions` a `List<List<string>>`, or anything that's `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`, even `List<string[]>` should work.